# Graphite not showing labels when rendered using wildcards

Tags: graphite

In order to generate graphs in graphite, i am using the URL render API. My URL is of the form-

`<IP>/render?&target=stats.beta.*.ip-10-0-0-179.counter.ant.*.*.succeeded&title=Notification&lineMode=connected`

The graph does have a title, but the individual five lines do not have any alias. The alias function doesn't work with wildcards.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want the individual graphs that match under the '*' wildcards to have labels below the graph so that they are identifiable. All i have now is multiple coloured lines without any legend.

Comment: Try &hideLegend=0 in the URL

Answer (score 1):

`aliasByNode(seriesList, *nodes)` works with wildcards. The function name is quite confusing, it simply splits the key by dots and takes i-th value specified as second argument. It is indexed from 0.

```
&target=aliasByNode(ganglia.*.cpu*.load5, 1)
                            ^
                            \ name the series by this part
```

you can specify multiple parts to use as a lengend:

```
   aliasByNode(localhost.*.cpu-{system,user,wait}),0,2)
                  ^           ^
                  \-----------\-should take these two -> 'localhost-cpu-system'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alias wildcards, you should use the [aliasByNode()](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.12/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasByNode) function. And as was mentioned by talonx, combine that `with hidelegend`